# Restricting CPAN to upgrade non-core modules only

Tags: perl, cpan

I frequently use the cpan `upgrade` command to bring my Perl modules to their latest versions. Regrettably  on distributions like CentOS which use ancient versions of Perl it attempts to upgrade perl itself along with other modules like B::X. Is there some way I could combine the ease and power of `upgrade` but not attempt (and fail) at upgrading core modules? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the system perl.  Install your own and start from that.  Even when there isn't an ancient perl.

You will have to exclude not just core modules, but also distributions that depend on newer versions of core modules, and distributions that depend on those distributions...
It's a battle you can't win and shouldn't even try to.

BTW, the CPAN-trying-to-upgrade-perl bug was *really really ancient*; are you really seeing it?

Comment: Apologies. cpan does not try to upgrade perl but does give a `Failed during this command....JESSE/perl-5.12.2..` Its the attempts to install B::X modules that I was trying to avoid. But you are right. Building my own perl is the obvious way to go.

Comment: I am using perl-5.8.8 (rpm: perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.2) on CentOS5.5. `perldoc perlhist` tells me that my perl will be 5 years old in a month and can officially go to school ;)